# In Opentok-react-native, how do I get various events information like client connected, disconnected and so on

Tags: react-native, opentok

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any way to find various callbacks in [opentok-react-native](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native) library like when user has connected, disconnected, reconnecting and so on. I even found the documentation for [OTSession](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/blob/master/docs/OTSession.md) where they have described the various events, but these are not working. These all events get called all together.

Video call is working fine, but I want to perform various action depending upon these events

```
renderVideoView(data) {
console.log("rendering view view,, ", data);

return (
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      backgroundColor: R.Colors.COLOR_VIDEO_BACKGROUND
    }}
  >
    <OTSession
      ref={ref => {
        this.OTSession = ref;
      }}
      connectionCreated={ console.log("connection created")}
      connectionDestroyed={ console.log("connection destroyed")}
      sessionConnected={ console.log("Client connect to a session")}
      sessionDisconnected={
        console.log("Client disConnect to a session")
      }
      sessionReconnected={() => console.log("session reconnected")}
      apiKey={this.apiKey}
      sessionId={data.sessionId}
      token={data.token}
    >
      <OTSubscriber style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} />

      <View style={styles.publisherStyle}>
        <OTPublisher
          properties={{
            publishAudio: this.state.publishAudio,
            cameraPosition: this.state.cameraPosition,
            publishVideo: this.state.publishVideo
          }}
          style={{ width: 90, height: 107, padding: 2 }}
        />
      </View>

      {this.renderViewAtCenter()}
      {this.renderBottomView()}
      {this.renderTopView()}
    </OTSession>
  </View>
);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

To set the event listeners via the `OTSession` component, please use the `eventHandlers` prop like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { OTSession, OTPublisher, OTSubscriber } from 'opentok-react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.apiKey = '';
    this.sessionId = '';
    this.token = '';
    this.sessionEventHandlers = {
      connectionCreated: event =>  { 
          console.log("connection created", event);
      },
      connectionDestroyed: event =>  { 
          console.log("connection destroyed", event);
      },
      sessionConnected: event => { 
          console.log("Client connect to a session")
      },
      sessionDisconnected: event => {
        console.log("Client disConnect to a session")
      },
      sessionReconnected: event => {
        console.log("session reconnected")
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <OTSession apiKey={this.apiKey} sessionId={this.sessionId} token={this.token} eventHandlers={this.sessionEventHandlers}>
          <OTPublisher style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          <OTSubscriber style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
        </OTSession>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've also gone ahead and filed an [issue](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/issues/229) on the repo to improve documentation for the `OTSession` component.