# Opentok React Native is not publishing anything

Tags: reactjs, react-native, opentok, tokbox

I'm using the [`opentok-react-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-react-native) library in my app and I want to publish audio and video streams as audio/video call. I followed the documentation to the letter, but I'm not able to connect.

Here is what I've tried:

```
render() {

return (

    <OTSession
          apiKey={ this.state.api_key }
          sessionId={ this.state.appointment.opentok_session }
          token={ this.state.appointment.opentok_token }
          connectionCreated={ console.warn('connected') }
          connectionDestroyed={ console.warn('destroyed') }
          sessionConnected={ console.warn('session connected') }
          sessionReconnecting={ console.warn('session reconnecting') }
          sessionReconnected={ console.warn('session re connected') }
          sessionDisconnected={ console.warn('session destroyed') }
          streamCreated={ console.warn('stream created') }
          streamDestroyed={ console.warn('stream destroyed') }
        >
          <OTPublisher
            properties={{ publishAudio: true, publishVideo: true }}
            style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
          />
          <OTSubscriber  style={{ flex: 1 }} />
        </OTSession>

    )

}
```

I've written the exact same component in the other app - there are two apps. As soon as the component loads, I get all the `console.warn()`, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

It looks like you're trying to listen for the events via individual props. Please note that you need to use the `eventHandlers` prop to set the event listeners. Here's an example of how to set event listeners for the [`OTSession`](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/blob/master/docs/OTSession.md) component: [In Opentok-react-native, how do I get various events information like client connected, disconnected and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455675/in-opentok-react-native-how-do-i-get-various-events-information-like-client-con?answertab=active#tab-top)

You also need to specify the `width` and `height` for the `OTSubscriber` component so the library knows what size to create the native view.

I also recommend checking out the [OpenTok-React-Native-Samples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native-samples) repo for reference.